# How do I get tags to only display on posts that have that tag?

Tags: tags

I’m trying to add tags to my blog posts.

I’ve created a tags group with the handle ‘default’.

In Setting/Fields I’ve got a field called bodyElements which is setup as a matrix, and within bodyElements I’ve added to the Configuration a block type called Tags with a handle of ‘tags’, and then within that there’s a field called Tags with a handle of ‘blogTags’ and this is set as the Field Type of “Tags” and the Source is set as “Tags”.

Now when I go to a blog post, I can type in my content and click the button to add a Tag. I can then type in a tag and it attaches to that particular entry.

The issue I’m having is that when I view the blog posts on the front end, the tags are showing up on every single post, even though they don’t have those tags attached to them.

On https://craftcms.com/support/active-tags it says to insert the following code to display only the tags that are in use

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(null) %}
<ul>
    {% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(entries) %}
        <li>{{ tag.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but that doesn’t display the tags at all.

My blog section has a handle of ‘blog’, so in the above code I tried replacing ‘news’ with ‘blog’ and still no tags appear.

The only way I can get tags to appear on my posts is by using the following code:

```
{% for tag in craft.tags.group(‘default’) %}
    <li><a href="{{ url('blog/tags/'~tag.id) }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

but the above code caused the tags to appear on every single blog post, even if they’re not tagged with anything.

How do I get the tags to only appear on the posts the tags are attached to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using at the moment is trying to output the tags that are in use on *any/all* entries:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(null) %}
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to output the tags only for the *current* entry, right?

*This is explained with very useful examples in the [documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/tags-fields#templating).*

**Solution**

Assuming you already have the `entry` variable set, you could do the following:

```
<ul>
    {% for tag in craft.tags.relatedTo(entry) %}
        <li>{{ tag.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Another example adapted from the docs:

```
{% set tags = entry.tagsFieldHandle %}

{% if tags | length %}

    <ul>
        {% for tag in tags %}
            <li>{{ tag.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    <ul>

{% endif %}
```

You first set the variable `tags` to the tags related to your `entry`. Then, you check if there are tags related to the entry. If there are, you iterate over them.

Comment: @Wayne Does this answer help you? If not, ask more questions. If so, please mark it as accepted!

Comment: Using the second example of your code I get the following error. Internal Server Error

Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "tagsFieldHandle".

Comment: That's because `tagsFieldHandle` is only an example. You should replace it with the handle of your `tags` field. At some point you created a field in the Craft control panel to select tags for your post, right? Use the handle of that field.